# Calling a javascript function from Python, sending arguments to Javascript, receiving results back to Python

Tags: javascript, python, function, calling-convention

I need to make use of a javascript calculator script, sending arguments (two values) from Python to the javascript function, having the javascript function process the two values and return a result (a value) that is sent back to the Python program.

I am looking at Node.js as a possible solution.  I've tried to use pyexecjs and pyv8 but have not found current versions.

Any suggestions?